# problem regarding ant build.xml

Tags: apache2, apache-ant

when I am using ant tool to do the ant tasks like 
1)ant gsn
2)ant stop etc

I am getting an error=> 
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

pleas help me to recover form this problem.

Comment: why this question be asked here?

Answer (score 0):

The directory you are running the ant command from should have a build.xml.
If that doesn't contain the build.xml then use ant -f .
Please do a simple google search and post your questions in the right forums.